# Oracle SOA Suite WS-Policies and Bound Properties

Tags: oracle, soa, wsse

I'm attempting to do a query from a third-party website using Oracle SOA Suite. What the SOAP message should have is a header with this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
<wsse:Username>USERNAME_HERE</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD_HERE</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">q3rLryh0dfQ1BucKrtpagw==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2012-11-26T20:38:56.682Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

However, there isn't a clear way to do this in JDeveloper. How do I configure my WS Policy and Properties in JDeveloper and SOA Suite to produce a SOAP message with the above header?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to do this

1. Assign the policy to the partnerlink, right click on the partnerlink and chose Configure WS Policies, choose the policy you wish to configure. 
   For information on how to configure a policy during development [Enabling Security with Policies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b32511/creating_policies.htm#CIHDEEDE)
2. Conversely you can configure your policy using OWSM on the administration console. 
   For information on how to configure a OWSM policy [Managing Web Service Policies Refer to Chapter 7 and 8](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b32511/creating_policies.htm#CIHDEEDE)